# Where does the bootstrap standard error live in the boot class?

Tags: r

Consider the following bootstrap:

```
library(MASS)
library(boot)

# c)
set.seed(1)
boot.fn= function(data, index) mean(data[index])
output=boot(Boston$medv, boot.fn, 1000)
```

If we run `print(output)`, we get

```
Call:
boot(data = Boston$medv, statistic = boot.fn, R = 1000)


Bootstrap Statistics :
    original      bias    std. error
t1* 22.53281 0.008517589   0.4119374
```

However, when I examine the `output` object, I cannot find values representing the bootstrap statistics. Where is `original`, `bias` and `std. error` in the actual `output` object returned by boot?

Comment: They are calculated by `print.boot` and not stored in the `boot` object.

Comment: Can I capture it from `print.boot` somehow?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are calculated by `print.boot` and not stored in the `boot` object. Look at `getAnywhere(print.boot)` for the details.

You can either calculate these values yourself or use `capture.output`.

For your example:

```
#original:
output$t0
#bias:
mean(output$t)-output$t0
#se: 
sd(output$t)
```

Answer (score 4):

This command seems to work:

```
apply(output$t,2,sd)[1]
```

Comment: Since you are formally posting an answer to an older question. It would be most helpful that you support your purported answer with some code and the output that results from using your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the standard errors by using summary:

```
se <- summary(output)$bootSE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
output_tab <- t(rbind(
  # this grabs the original coefficients
  output$t0, 
  # bootstrapped coefficients' standard errors
  apply(output$t, 2, function(x) sd(x, ra.rm = TRUE))  
))  

output_tab
#         [,1]      [,2]
#[1,] 22.53281 0.4106622
```

Answer (score 0):

Extracting se using `capture.output`

```
library(stringr)

x <- capture.output(output) # store the output as text
x <- str_extract(x ,"^t1.*$") # grab the line that starts with t1
x <- x[!is.na(x)] # remove all the lines we don't need
se <- as.numeric(unlist(str_extract_all(x, '[0-9.]+$'))) # extract the final value (se)
#[1] 0.4119374
```