# How to bootstrap with lapply? bootstrap error with boot() in R

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I am getting an error  `"Error in statistic(data, original, ...) : unused argument (original)"` when trying to execute the code below. Specifically, I am trying to apply a function and bootstrap those results for each plot#. Am I missing something straightforward here?

```
    library(codyn) # has sample dataset called pplots
    library(boot)

    str(pplots)

    stability <- function(x){
  mean(multivariate_change(x,
                           species.var = "species",
                           time.var = "year",
                           abundance.var = "relative_cover",
                           replicate.var = "plot")$composition_change)
}

boot_obj <- lapply(splitspplots,boot,statistic = stability,R = 20)
boot_obj <- lapply(splitspplots,myBootFun)

myBootFun <- function(x,i) {
  lapply(x[i],boot, statistic=stability, R = 10)
}
myBootFun <- function(x,i) {
  boot(x[i], statistic=stability, R = 10)
}
splitspplots <- split(pplots,pplots$plot)
lapply(splitspplots, print(myBootFun))
```

Comment: I don't know package codyn, but if you are using package boot (maybe indirectly) then you need to study the description of the `statistic` parameter in `help("boot")`.

Comment: Thanks! ended up gettting the code to run but it doesn't generate bias or std error stats. any ideas?

Comment: Bias and standard error are calculated by the `print` method. Either call `print` or calculate them manually: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19963673/1412059

Comment: Also, if you don't use `i` inside the `stability` function, you are not doing bootstrapping.

Comment: Is that i instead of the x inside the function? That does not work for me.

Comment: Please stop a moment and *think*  about how bootstrap works. The `boot` function creates a random sample of indices and you need to use these indices for subsetting your data. Compare with the example in the linked question above.

Comment: I see that in the stability function I use then x[i], however I am unsure how the boot works. Does the 'mybootfunction' have to by lapply'd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured a different way to do this that works as well.

I used a for loop to loop across different groups/sites, but I do not show that here. Here is the bootstrap code.

```
data_sampled <- data_grouped %>%
    group_by(SITE_ID) %>%
    crossing(id = seq(100)) %>% # create replicate dataframes
    sample_n(size = n(), replace = T) # sample dataframes
```